# Returning an array outside of main

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to return an array outside of main. It keeps giving me the memory location only but not values. I've tried using for loops and changing return type to int but I just can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

```
private int[] sides;

public int[] getSides(){
    return sides;

    }
```

Comment: No such thing as "memory location" in java... You haven't actually created an array: use `new int[5]`; http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Where is `main`?  If `sides` is private, why are you returning it?

Comment: Please post your whole code so that we can help you! Also post the whole error log!

Answer (score 2):

Because array doesn't override the `toString()` from `Object` it gets the default. You can use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29), or you can iterate the array and print the elements yourself.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getSides()));
```

or something like a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to iterate like

```
for (int i : getSides()) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That should work, has the array actually been initialised yet?